# How to compare multibyte characters in C

Tags: c, compare

I try to parse text and find some characters in it. I use the code below. It works with normal characters like `abcdef` but it does not work with `öçşğüı`. GCC gives compilation warnings. What should I do to work with `öçşğüı`?

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char * text = "öçşğü";
    int i=0;

    text = strdup(text);

    while (text[i])
    {       
        if(text[i] == 'ö')
        {
            printf("ö \n");
        }

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Warning :

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
```

---

There are 10 addresses when I print address of char in while loop

```
printf("%d : %p \n", i, text[i]);
```

output :

```
0 : 0xffffffc3 
1 : 0xffffffb6 
2 : 0xffffffc3 
3 : 0xffffffa7 
4 : 0xffffffc5 
5 : 0xffffff9f 
6 : 0xffffffc4 
7 : 0xffffff9f 
8 : 0xffffffc3 
9 : 0xffffffbc
```

and `strlen` is 10.

But if I use `abcde`:

```
0 : 0x61 
1 : 0x62 
2 : 0x63 
3 : 0x64 
4 : 0x65
```

and `strlen` is 5.

---

If I use `wchar_t` for text output is

```
0 : 0xa7c3b6c3 
1 : 0x9fc49fc5 
2 : 0xbcc3
```

and `strlen` is 10, `wcslen` is 3.

Comment: I think that's because the umlauts are considered another character. You might have to either check for actual strings instead of characters or take `oe` instead of `ö` as input.

Comment: llvm explicitly give an error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
        if(text[i] == 'ö')

Comment: `strncmp()` may be helpful.

Comment: Use `wchar_t` instead of char. Use `L` suffix on all string literals and character literals. Use `wcslen` instead of `strlen`.

Comment: @MikeCAT To compare OP should use `wscmp` .

Comment: just to add to whar Mr. @Lundin said, add `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: In addition, even if in your case everything is hard-coded in the same file, you need to make sure that you use the same charset for comparison, even if not multibyte.

Comment: Read this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html then try again.

Comment: @Lundin this will work with a program that doesn't read or write any character data. Once you try that, you suddenly need to care about locales and encodings and stream orientations and whatnot.

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", 'ö'); while (*text) printf("%d\n", *text++);` to get greater insight.

Comment: Embedding non-ascii in the source code is not covered by any standards

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @M.M Outside a c-string perhaps.  But, it's more of an editor question:  will/won't display/manipulate (e.g. is the font set loaded).  In compiler, "<asc><utf1-utf3><asc2>..." will get parsed as I think it only looks for 0x00 or `\"` within.  compiler would need special logic to carp on it--just to be pedantic. Should work fine in comments, too (both K&R and ANSI).  OP couldn't compile because he was using single quotes instead of double (e.g. a utf8 codepoint is 1-4 chars).  Based on the diagnostic, compiler understood utf8 fine. OP had broken code, and his self-answer isn't much better.

Comment: @CraigEstey even inside the string, compilers are only required to accept source consisting of A-Z, a-z, 0-9,  29 standard punctuation characters, and standard whitespace.

Comment: @M.M Scanning a string constant, you start with `"` and go until `"`, absorbing `\"` along the way.  To reject, you'd need a range check [or table lookup] inside your loop--slowing it down.  What would a German pgmr say if they couldn't use an umlaut in a string constant?  Most langs support utf8 and the C compilers I've seen do, spec notwithstanding.  Why stand on ceremony when the result would less practical/international?  I'm not suggesting that _symbols_ get utf8, only string constants and comments--which they already do.  If you're agin `wchar_t` and `L"abc"`, I'm with you 100%

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm only talking about what is guaranteed by specs (as indicated in my first comment)

Answer (score 2):

To go through each of the characters in the string, you can use `mblen`. You also need to set the correct locale (the encoding represented by the multi byte string), so that `mblen` can correctly parse the multi byte string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    char * text = "öçşğü";
    int i=0, char_len;

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.utf8");

    while ((char_len = mblen(&text[i], MB_CUR_MAX)) > 0)
    {
        /* &text[i] contains multibyte character of length char_len */
        if(memcmp(&text[i], "ö", char_len) == 0)
        {
            printf("ö \n");
        }

        i += char_len;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are 2 types of string representation, using multi-byte (8-bit bytes) or wide byte (size depends on platform). Multi-byte representation has the advantage it can be represented using `char *` (usual c string as in your code), but has disadvantage that multiple bytes represent a character. Wide string is represented using `wchar_t *`. `wchar_t` has the advantage that one wchar_t is one character (However as @anatolyg pointed out, this assumption can still go wrong in platforms where wchar_t is not able to represent all possible characters).

Have you looked at your source code using a hex editor? The string `"öçşğü"` actually is represented by multi byte string `c3 b6 c3 a7 c5 9f c4 9f c3 bc` in memory (UTF-8 encoding), of course with zero termination. You see 5 characters just because the string is rendered correctly by your UTF-8 aware viewer/browser. It is simple to realize that `strlen(text)` returns 10 for this, whereas the above code loops only 5 times.

If you use wide-byte string, it can be done as explained by @WillBriggs.

Comment: Your code asks `Why is this needed?`, which seems weird. Did you copy it from somewhere together with this misleading comment, or do you wonder yourself why you need `strdup`? I think there is absolutely no reason to use `strdup` here (BTW `strdup` must be paired with `free`, which is missing in your code).

Comment: I just wanted to ask the original poster, why he used strdup. Of course, it is not needed, just for parsing. I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @user1969104 thanks for answer. I tried your code in linux but never print `ö` to console. You can see on http://ideone.com/2arnRE . But it works with `abcde`

Comment: @user4757345 Please print `char_len` after the loop. If it is `-1`, `mblen` might have failed. This might be due to incorrect locale. Please see the output of the command `locale -a` to see if `en_US.utf8` is present in the output. If not, please use any utf8 string present in the output e.g. C.UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standards surrounding embedding non-ASCII characters directly in your source file.

Instead, the C11 standard specifies that you can use Unicode code points:

```
wchar_t text[] = L"\u00f6\u00e7\u015f\u0131\u011f";

// Print whole string
wprintf(L"%s\n", text);

// Test individual characters
for (size_t i = 0; text[i]; ++i)
{
    if ( text[i] == u'\u00f6' )
        // whatever...
}
```

---

If you are in Windows then you face an extra problem that the Windows console can't print Unicode characters by default. You need to do the following:

- Change the console to use a TrueType monospaced font which includes glyphs for the characters you are trying to print. (I used "DejaVu Sans Mono" for this example)
- In the source code, call the function `_setmode(1, _O_WTEXT);` , which will need `#include <fcntl.h>`.

To restore normal text afterwards you can `_setmode(1, _O_TEXT);`.

Of course, if you are outputting to a file or to a Win32 API function then you don't need to do those steps.

Comment: thanks for answer @M.M. But I get this error `error: ‘u’ undeclared (first use in this function)`. If I changed `u` with `L` code works.

Comment: OK. Your compiler may not support C11 (or you didn't invoke it in C11 mode if it does)

Answer (score 0):

See wiki here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8  In particular, there is a table with the bit patterns.

Here's another way to scan/convert a utf-8 string into a `codepoint` [not exact, just an example--refer to wiki]:

```
// utf8scan -- convert utf8 to codepoints (example)

char inpbuf[1000];
char uni[8];

typedef union {
    char utf8[4];
    unsigned int code;
} codepoint_t;

codepoint_t outbuf[1000];

// unidecode -- decode utf8 char into codepoint
// RETURNS: updated rhs pointer
char *
unidecode(codepoint_t *lhs,char *rhs)
{
    int idx;
    int chr;

    idx = 0;
    lhs->utf8[idx++] = *rhs++;

    for (;  ;  ++rhs, ++idx) {
        chr = *rhs;

        // end of string
        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        // start of new ascii char
        if ((chr & 0x80) == 0)
            break;

        // start of new unicode char
        if (chr & 0x40)
            break;

        lhs->utf8[idx] = chr;
    }

    return rhs;
}

// main -- main program
int
main(void)
{
    char *rhs;
    codepoint_t *lhs;

    rhs = inpbuf;
    lhs = outbuf;

    for (;  *rhs != 0;  ++lhs) {
        lhs->code = 0;

        // ascii char
        if ((*rhs & 0x80) == 0)
            lhs->utf8[0] = *rhs++;

        // get/skip unicode char
        else
            rhs = unidecode(lhs,rhs);
    }

    // add EOS
    lhs->code = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way to handle wide characters is as, well, wide characters.

```
wchar_t myWord[] = L"Something";
```

This will do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t * text = L"öçşğü";
    int i = 0;

    while (text[i])
    {
        if (text[i] == L'ö')
        {
            wprintf(L"ö \n");
        }

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you're in Visual Studio, like me, recall that the console window doesn't handle Unicode well.  You can redirect it to a file and examine the file, and see the `ö`.

Comment: In my opinion, using `wchar_t` is the *worst* way, because in Visual Studio they are 16-bit, and require UTF-16 encoding. So code that ignores encoding (like `i++`) will have its bugs concealed - you will see the bugs in maybe 0.1% strings, instead of maybe 10% strings.